# Algorithm for computing the rank of the fundamental group of a graph?

Tags: algebraic-topology, algorithms, graph-theory

I've been learning a bit about applications of algebraic topology to graph theory and I'm interested in figuring out how to compute the fundamental group $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ of an arbitrary graph $G=(V,E)$. It seems to me you could use a simple DFS to compute the number of distinct cycles with any arbitrary $x_0$ as the base point. That would give you the number of generators in $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and you'd know it's just the free group over those generators. Am I off base? If not, is that the most computationally efficient way to go about it? I'm pretty sure I can't (in general) use any simple formula like the Euler chracteristic...

Comment: You can argue, for each connected component K of the graph G, that you can find a spanning tree for K, then the edges of G-T generate the fundamental group; each loop based at p will pass thru an edge in G-T; conversely, for every edge in G-T, you define a unique loop.

Comment: Interesting -- what is the best algorithmic way to determine the maximal spanning tree? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but let me think things thru more carefully and see what I can come up with; the proof of the existence of the tree is constructive, so it would not be too hard to turn it into an algorithm .

Comment: thanks gary. do you have a link to the proof?

Comment: No problem; here is the proof; I posted this question to some other site: http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist;task=show_msg;msg=1979.0001 . You may also want to look into the Schreier Subgroup Lemma, which allows you to find the stabilizer of an element under a group action; an element of the stabilizer of some g in the graph G can be seen as a loop based at g. The Schreier subgroup lemma is an application of Reidemeister-Schreier to finding a generating set for a subgroup H og a group G using a transversal T for the quotient group G/H.

Comment: See too, re the above comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier's_subgroup_lemma

Comment: Cool, thanks! Interesting stuff. I found what I think is a pretty easy way to do it for a finite graph (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64192/the-fundamental-group-of-k-3-3-relationship-between-its-generators-and-embed) but I'm still a little confused, because I keep getting the Euler characteristic V - E for the utility graph K_{3,3} to be 4, meaning its fundamental group is free on 4 generators, which confuses me because I know it can be embedded in the torus. what am I missing?

Comment: Please give me a little bit of time; I will be busy for a few days, but I will look into it.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else wants to know the answer, I figured it out. The fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ of a graph $X=(V,E)$ is the free group on $k$ generators, $k = 1 - |V| + |E|$,. This is given by $ 1 - \chi$, where $\chi$ is the usual Euler characteristic, $V-E$.

Comment: Correct: if $T$ is a spanning tree of the graph, then $\pi_1(X)$ is freely generated "by" the vertices in $X$ that are not in $T$. But you don't need to *find* the maximal spanning tree, you just need to count how edges it has. Since a connected tree with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, the formula follows.

Comment: @Arturo I think you meant "edges" in the first line. :)

Comment: @Srivatsan: Oops; quite so. Too bad I can't edit it anymore...

Comment: To be clear, this is correct for connected graphs.  For possibly disconnected graphs, you need to count just the vertices and edges in the component of the basepoint.